# What is the Default Execution Manner of AsyncTasks in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

android `Asynctask` has been modified quite frequently between different API-levels. I'm developing an Application in which i've to upload images to FTP server. i want to do that in serialized order (images upload after one-another by one image upload per asyntask). I understand the `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`   and `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` stuff, but i just want some clarity about what is the default behavior of asynctask ( my min. target API is ICS 4.0 ). if i simply execute say 10 asyncs' in a loop, will they go to thread queue and execute one by one or they'll just go parallel ?

Comment: If you control threads by yourself, I think, directly using `Thread` class and `Handler` class may be short cut. It will be all under your control!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the `AsyncTask` documentation:

> When first introduced, `AsyncTask`s were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool
>   of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting
>   with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid
>   common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with
>   `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

So, with min target of 14, they will be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use one async task with loop inside `doInBackground()`? If you want to have control over them, you can invoke second async task in `onPostExecute()` of first.

Comment: that was : async task Inside loop.